# Inject multiple implementations in abp.io .NET5/6/Core

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, abp

**UPDATE 2: FIXED THE CODE at the end**

I have the abp.io service below with 2 parameters in the constructor instantiated via DI.
One of them, `IOutcomeWriter`, has 2 implementations.

I'd like to define at runtime which of the implementations of `IOutcomeWriter` to use.

This is the main service:

```cs
public class UCManagerService
    : DomainService, IUCManagerService, ITransientDependency {
    private readonly IUCInputReader _inputReader;
    
    // This field can have 2 or 3 implementations.
    private readonly IOutcomeWriter _outcomeWriter;

    public UCManagerService(
        IUCInputReader inputReader, IOutcomeWriter outcomeWriter) {
        _inputReader = inputReader;
        _outcomeWriter = outcomeWriter;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync() {
        // start processing the input and generate the output
        var input = _inputReader.GetInput());
        // do something
        // ...
        _outcomeWriter.Write(something);
    }
}
```

The main service is registered in the `AbpModule` together with with `IUCInputReader` and the 2 implementations of `IOutcomeWriter`:

```cs
[DependsOn(
    typeof(SwiftConverterDomainModule),
    typeof(AbpAutofacModule)  // <= use Autofac in some way (I don't know how)
)]
public class ProgramAppModule : AbpModule {

    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context) {
        context.Services.AddTransient<IUCManagerService, UCManagerService>();
        context.Services.AddTransient<IUCInputReader, UCInputReader>();
            
        // 2 implementations of IOutcomeWriter
        context.Services.AddTransient<IOutcomeWriter, OutcomeWriter1>();
        context.Services.AddTransient<IOutcomeWriter, OutcomeWriter2>();
    }
}
```

What I would like is to instantiate `UCManagerService` sometimes with `OutcomeWriter1` and sometimes with `OutcomeWriter2`, according to some values in `appsettings.json`:

```cs
IList<JobSetting> jobsToSet = _configuration.GetSection("Jobs")
    .Get<List<JobSetting>>();
foreach (JobSetting jobToSet in jobsToSet) {
    // If jobsToSet.SomeValue == 'MyValue1' following line should have to
    // require a IUCManagerService using OutcomeWriter1. If it is
    // 'MyValue2' it'd use OutcomeWriter2, and so on:
    var service = abpApplication.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUCManagerService>();  // ???
    // do something else with service
    // ...
}
```

Finally, if a tomorrow I add an `OutcomeWriter3` I would just like to register it in `ProgramAppModule.ConfigureServices(...)` and of course use a different key in `appsettings.json`.

Comment: You are stating that you want to switch the `IOutcomeWriter` implementation based on the `Jobs` configuration setting, but does its value change while the application is running, or will the value be constant during the applications lifetime? In other words, is it okay to restart the application if the `Jobs` configuration setting needs to change?

Comment: It's unclear whether the code comment `<= use Autofac in some way (I don't know how)` is relevant to your question or not. Is this something your question is about and which an answer to? If so, you might want to add more context or move that part to a new question on SO. If it is irrelevant, you might want to remove the comment, as it would only be confusing.

Comment: @Steven, your comments are right. Code fixed. About the questions:
- Jobs configuration setting change: ok to restart. Alternative: clean and re-init the DI regs. The key point is that I might have N jobs, 1 requiring OutcomWriter1, the 2nd OutcomWriter2, 3rd OutcomWriter1 again, ...
- Autofac: this is not clear to be. It is in used the abp.io framework I use. The point is that I'm still learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the `IOutcomeWriter` to differ based on the currently executed job. In other words, that means that you need to *dynamically* switch the writer based on its context.

The fact that it you need to change it *dynamically*, it means that is not a problem that can be solved solely using your DI configuration, because DI configurations are best kept *static*.

Instead, you need to mix and match a few concepts. First of all, you need a way to set the used job in the context. For instance:

```cs
// DI configuration
services.AddScoped<JobContext>();

// Execution of a job
using (var scope = abpApplication.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.GetRequiredService<JobContext>();
    context.CurrentJob = typeof(MyFirstJob);

    var job = scope.GetRequiredService<MyFirstJob>();
    var job.Execute();
}
```

In this example, `JobContext` is a class that holds the data that is used during the execution of a certain job. It is registered as `Scoped` to allow this data to be available for multiple classes within the same scope.

Now using this new `JobContext`, you can build an adapter for `IOutcomeWriter` that can forward the incoming call to the right implementation based on its injected `JobContext`. This might look as follows:

```cs
public class JobSpecificOutcomeWriter : IOutcomeWriter
{
    private readonly JobContext context;
    private readonly IList<JobSetting> settings;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IOutcomeWriter> writers;

    public JobSpecificOutcomeWriter(
        JobContext context,
        IList<JobSetting> settings,
        IEnumerable<IOutcomeWriter> writers)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.settings = settings;
        this.writers = writers;
    }

    // Implement all IOutcomeWriter methods by forwarding them to the
    // CurrentWriter.
    object IOutcomeWriter.SomeMethod(object a) =>
        this.CurrentWriter.SomeMethod(a);

    private IOutcomeWriter CurrentWriter
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO: Based on the current context and the settings,
            // select the proper outcome writer from the writers list.
        }
    }
}
```

When `JobSpecificOutcomeWriter` is injected into `UCManagerService` (or any component for that matter), it transparently allows the proper writer to be used, without the consuming class from knowing about this.

The tricky part, actually, is to now configure your DI container correctly using `JobSpecificOutcomeWriter`. Depending on which DI Container you use, your mileage might vary and with the MS.DI Container, this is actually quite complicated.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IOutcomeWriter>(c =>
    new JobSpecificOutcomeWriter(
       context: c.GetRequiredService<JobContext>(),
       settings: jobsToSet,
       writers: new IOutcomeWriter[]
       {
           c.GetRequiredService<MyFirstJob>(),
           c.GetRequiredService<MySecondJob>(),
           c.GetRequiredService<MyThirdJob>(),
       });

services.AddTransient<MyFirstJob>();
services.AddTransient<MySecondJob>();
services.AddTransient<MyThirdJob>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be the solution. What about jobsToSet[0] needs `OutcomeWriter1` and `jobsToSet[1]` requires `OutcomeWriter2`? I modified again the question to let it be more clear. Tnx

Comment: In this case you might want to rephrase your question to explain what it is you are trying to achieve. For instance, show the exact graphs you are trying to create and explain how this relates to the configuration you defined.

Comment: did it right now

Comment: See my update..